# Functions in external javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, function, dom, external-script

Problem is really simple and I have spent 2 hours on it and I haven't got any ideas. There isn't any libraries like Jquery. And it is one of the simpliest functions on the world. I'm sure that the function is working because when I make it inline code, it works. And here's the code:

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="vars.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="font.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="site.css">
    <script src="viewport-units-buggyfill.js" ></script>
    <script src="default.js"></script>
    <script src="site.js"></script>
    <!--<script>
        function byId(id)
        {
           return document.getElementById(id);
        }
    </script>-->
</head
```

And I invoke it with inline onclick:

```
<section id="den" onclick="byId('den').innerHTML = 'red';" class="gizlimenu">
                </section>
```

And here's the external "default.js":

```
function byId(id){
return document.getElementById(id);
}
```

As you seen, if I activate the comment code, everything runs OK.
And here's the screenshot of Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]

I'm using Brackets Live Preview to view the page. The other code stuff is because of that.

Note: And I realized that it is working when I run it directly from index.html. But it isn't working with Brackets or from a server (even a Dropbox or Gdrive server). So I think this can be a problem with the path of the script.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try using an absolute path, like '/.../default.js'? Note: not the path of the server, but from the hostname.

Comment: _So I think this can be a problem with the path of the script._ Have you checked that? Look in the network tab to see what's being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the possible error in the network path for locating your script, I'm actually suggesting you to not implement byId... after analyzing what you want to achieve you don't need it at all.

You are clicking an element and on click you are trying to find the same element so you can alter the innerHTML property of it? It's like watching a dog chasing its tail.

You don't need to find an element that you just interacted with in the DOM. *this* will give you direct accedd to the element that you just clicked. So you can pass it as parameter to any function, or you can modify it inline.

Your example:

```
<section id="den" onclick="byId('den').innerHTML = 'red';" class="gizlimenu">
            </section>
```

Can turn into:

```
<section id="den" onclick="this.innerHTML = 'red';" class="gizlimenu">
            </section>
```

See a running example:

http://jsbin.com/feyidoweco/7/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't fix the primary issue here, which is that OP's script is seemingly failing to load.

Comment: @JLRishe well, no one except himself can fix his problem.

Comment: The invocation section is just one of the invocations on my code. There are other elements which use the same function.  I know it could be easier if I use this but actually this wasn't my problem.